# Cannot open github.com and some other websites

Tags: ubuntu, internet-connection

I use Ubuntu 14.04. I cannot open github.com and many other websites since two weeks, I tried opening in my laptop and phone but nothing works.

I also tried in many browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Ubuntu's built-in browser) but nothing works. Is it a problem in my router's IP address or internet service provider? Because I use internet in phone and laptop via router.

I have a TP-Link router and service from BSNL.

Comment: Are you in India? I heard from someone on Stack Overflow that they were also having issues, as their ISP had blocked Github for some reason. Go complain to your ISP.

Comment: yes I'm Indian! and I'm definitely gonna complain about this. @MattDMo

Comment: We have no information about your network setup, your OS, what browsers and devices you've tried. What sites specifically are broken? What DNS are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 and I have tried opening those sites in Chrome, Firefox and Ubuntu's browser but nobody can open. I use tp link router and bsnl broadband. @slhck

Comment: You haven't answered all questions though… Now we know the OS and browsers. But what sites are broken? What DNS are you using? What happens when you run `ping github.com` and `nslookup github.com`? What's the output of `nm-tool`? Please [edit] and update your question.

Answer (score -1):

If the ISP has only blocked the DNS in their servers then you can change your router to use one of the public DNS providers, eg: Google 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 or OpenDNS 208.67.222.222 / 208.67.220.220

Comment: That's a bit of a long shot.. I would wait until there is more information given by the OP.

Comment: A wild guess what might apply, isn't really that helpful, if the user uses either of those DNS providers its not helpful at all.